# How to escape hyphen character in Python elasticsearch

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I'm using the basic elasticsearch library in python 3.

I have a query:

```
query = {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [{ "term": {"hostname": '"hal-pc"' } }]
            }
        }
    }
```

That I call with: 
`page = es.search(index = index_name, body=query, search_type='scan', scroll='2m')`

However I'm not getting any results. I can query on other fields so I know my query works, but when I add the search for a field with a hyphen in the value, I cannot find anything. How can I escape this character? I know that with normal ES queries you can send a message to configure your ES to respond to certain characters in certain ways, but I don't know how to do that in python.

Comment: Is the field `hostname` analyzed in elasticsearch mapping?

Comment: I don't know what that means - I don't maintain the ES. I have access to a kibana, and it appears as a text field, if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field `hostname` is analyzed in mapping, elasticsearch does not store the field value as is. Instead, it stores "hal-pc" as two separate terms: "hal" and "pc".So, the doc might not be obtained when search for "hal-pc" using `term` filter.

You can search for "hal-pc" using `Match` query to get the necessary result. Or, by making the field `hostname` field not-analyzed and using `term` query as is.

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "hostname": "hal-pc"
        }
    }
}
```

But, this might also return docs where hostname is just "hal" or just "pc" as well.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with ES to understand your answer. Can you provide a sample `Match` query as am example? And how I would make the field not analyzed?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. If I have several hostnames like "hal-pc", "abc-pc", "foo-pc", this will only give me "hal-pc" right? and I can combine this with other `bool` queries by having `{"query":{"bool":{stuff},"match":{stuff in your post}}}` right?

Comment: Check this out : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html#_term_query_with_text